# Starting a new pool. questions about payout levels

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-setup

We are still in a closed testing phase making sure our hardware and software are working properly. I would like to ask the community if setting payouts to a very low value like 0.01 is a smart thing to do or not. I know low payouts are good to a low powered miner but I am not sure if transaction fees will cause an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea as answered here

https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/7lrv3r/starting_a_new_pool_questions_arize/

the Tx fee would eat up 30% of miner profit...